# Google geocode and distancematrix discrepancies

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am working on a project which uses google for geocoding and calculating travel time, it mainly works fine, but I am seeing some inexplicable behaviour with the following case.

Using google maps, I can correctly see the route between 2 locations as 3.6 miles, but when I use google distance matrix for the same route, the api returns 151 miles.

(googlemaps api key obfuscated from urls)

1) Geocode the postcode LN68SD

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=LN68SD&key=MapsAPIKey&region=uk

geocode correctly returns location 53.2017314, -0.5642401 (Lincoln, UK)

2) Geocode the postcode LN57FB

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=LN57FB&key=MapsAPIKey&region=uk

geocode correctly returns location 53.2265083, -0.5246126 (Lincoln, UK)

3) Show the route between the two locations:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/53.2017314,+-0.5642401/53.226509094238281,+-0.52461260557174683

maps correctly returns 3.6 miles, 15 minutes

4) Get the distancematrix between the two locations:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=53.2017314,-0.5642401&destinations=53.2265090942383,-0.524612605571747,UK&key=MapsAPIKey&region=uk&mode=driving&units=imperial

distancematrix incorrectly states locations are 150 miles apart (Lincoln/London)

```
// 20170523131103
// https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=53.2017314,-0.5642401&destinations=53.2265090942383,-0.524612605571747,UK&key=MapsAPIKey&region=uk&mode=driving&units=imperial

{
  "destination_addresses": [
    "99-101 Newington Causeway, London SE1 6BN, UK"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "1 Chancery Cl, Lincoln LN6, UK"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "151 mi",
            "value": 243015
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "2 hours 53 mins",
            "value": 10354
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the request to the distance matrix (",UK" on the destinations).  If I fix that I [get the expected result](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=53.2017314,-0.5642401&destinations=53.2265090942383,-0.524612605571747&region=uk&mode=driving&units=imperial) ("3.6 mi")

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=53.2017314,-0.5642401&destinations=53.2265090942383,-0.524612605571747&region=uk&mode=driving&units=imperial

{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Waterside S, Lincoln LN5 7FB, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "1 Chancery Cl, Lincoln LN6, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3.6 mi",
                  "value" : 5864
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 mins",
                  "value" : 889
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```